# Reflective surface not reflecting after certain angle

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

I am making a low poly headlights for a car and I have made the inside of the lights from reflective surface (mixed ~90% glossy with diffuse and little bit of glass) but from a certain angle it's not reflecting at all and looks ugly and unrealistic:
[image]

But from the front it looks ok:
[image]

This is the geometry:
[image]

Please help me create reflective material that reflects light correctly no matter from what angle I look.

Comment: I don't think it's the reflections that are off, I think it's the transmission. Can't be sure though. Have you tried separating the components of the material? See how it looks without the glas, or without the glossy? 
Also as a hint: I wouldn't use glass here, you won't see the difference and the transparent shader produces far less noise.

Comment: Even pure glossy doesn't have the right reflections. What should I use instead? And since the new denoiser is OP I will just render at 1000 samples and all the noise from the glass will be gone.

Comment: If the reflections from a pure glossy shader seem off, make sure your reflected objects/BG isn't actually gray in that area. Happened to me often enough...

Comment: Oh, yea the world is completely gray. Thanks.